# Ubuntu Mining RX570 4GB Claymore amd-gpu pro low hashrate

Tags: mining, ubuntu

I've been able to get a much higher hashrate on other systems. These are the steps I've taken so far, getting ~ 17Mh/s.

Description:    **Ubuntu 17.10**
Kernel: **4.13.0-36-generic**

1. Install amdgpu-pro-17.40-492261 (used the --compute flag. This is the only way my machine will boot)
2. Flashed the BIOS (BIOS was found online)
   **atiflash -p -f 0 Anoraks_Sapphire RX 570 Pulse 4GB Hynix Elpida_memshift-1500.rom**
3. Ran this for OC
   **sudo bash -c 'echo 5 > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/pp_sclk_od'

   sudo bash -c 'echo 15 > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/pp_mclk_od'**
4. Claymore flags: -epsw x -mode 1 -ftime 10 -asm 1 -etha 0

I've also tried a kernel 'pre spectre meltdown' with no effect. Any help or advice would be much appreciated :) will send some ETH for a solution!

Update: I have noticed the SCLK & VDDC fluctuating while mining. Power goes from 95W to 105W and SCLK goes from 988Mhz to 1070Mhz...

[image]

Changing to Ubuntu 16.04 and Kernel 4.10 does not do anything.

Comment: Have changed: /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.vm_fragment_size=9 amdgpu.hw_i2c=1"

Comment: Have you tried running without flashing your BIOS?

Comment: Yeah, ~16Mh/s. Modding the BIOS doesn't really change much. When

Answer (score 0):

its a krenel issue, get ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS with kernel version 4.10.0.
any newer kernel and you will get up to -8 mh/s.

Comment: Does not make a difference.